# Async/Await is awaiting another?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have async function:

```
const getUser = async (query) => {
  const user = await Users.findOne(query);
  const feed = await Feeds.findOne({ user: user._id });
  console.log("Do this befor await above");

  return { user, feed };
};
```

Does it mean that JS delays on each await line, awaiting promise result and `console.log("Do this befor await above");` never runs before two `await` above?
Is it possible last await is returned faster then first and I get this:

`return {undefined, feed}`?

So, code after async calling is not blocking?

```
getUser();
console.log("Code below is not blocking...");
```

Comment: Yes, it awaits the first then the second and only then logs into the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `findOne` actually returns a promise:

> Does it mean that JS delays on each await line, awaiting promise result

Yes

> and console.log("Do this befor await above"); never runs before two await above?

Yes

> Is it possible last await is returned faster then first and I get this:

No. `Feeds.findOne` isn't even called until the promise returned by `Users.findOne` resolves.

Comment: So, what is reason then to use async if it blocks next executions lines? If I need call two await function independent?

Comment: Where I can pass test about async/await?

Comment: When the async function containing the await statements awaits, it goes to sleep and code outside of that function runs.